# Can we use AWS DynamoDB with jhipster?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, jhipster

Currently I am trying to build a Spring-Boot + Angular2 based application, however as per jHipster documentation that are providing MongoDB, Cassandra NoMysql DB. So, I just want to know that do jHipster provide support for AWS DynamoDB?

Comment: No, you're on your own for this.

Comment: Means, we can explicitly integrate/configure DynamoDB in JHipster app, right?

Comment: Yes it's just a spring boot app, see http://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-dynamodb

Comment: Thanks, Gael for your quick help!